# copy files from public windows server ec2 instance to private linux ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I have windows server 2016 ec2 instance in public subnet. In the same VPC, I have Linux (RHEL) instances in private subnet. I want to copy files from windows server to Linux instances. Any help???

Comment: WinSCP. It's SCP, but for Windows. It will work like an FTP client on the Windows machine and communicate using SSH to the GNU/Linux machine..

Comment: WinSCP is probably the best approach. If you need to automate it there are a few options, but going via S3 is very easy with the AWS tools. Resilio Sync is another effective option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow file transfer between the two instances:

1. Make sure there are relevant routes and security groups in place.

For example, you need a route between your private and public networks and you need to allow traffic on port 22 between the two instances.

2. On your windows machine, install a SCP client, like WinSCP, add the IP of the linux server and connect using a local user credentials.